# can i get correction on my Applescript error using else if...?

Tags: applescript

```
activate application "Logic Pro X"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Logic Pro"
    
        set tracks_window to title of first window whose title contains "- Tracks"
        


        if value of static text 1 of group 3 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window is "Track:" and value of UI element 1 of group 3 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window is 0 then click UI element 1 of group 3 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window

        else if value of static text 1 of group 2 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window is "Track:" and value of UI element 1 of group 2 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window is 0 then click UI element 1 of group 2 of list 1 of group 2 of window tracks_window


        end if

    end tell
end tell
```

Hi I'm new to programming.

let's say first <if~> line as Code1 and second <else if~> line as Code2 for convenience.

what i've been trying to do was
if Code1 doesn't work, execute Code2

the results of Code1 and Code2 are same on GUI.

but as the app varies the index of UI elements by on its situations, I had to use complexed if/else if.

each of Codes are working good when run separately (on correct condition)
but not on one script combining them with else if~.

**462:469:
syntax error: Expected “end” or “end tell” but found “else if”. (-2741)**

this was the message I got from Visual Studio Code when I run them.

so I tried to figure out by edit stuffs like else, end if
but didn't worked as I intended.

could anyone can help me how to solve this error?
thanks.

Comment: Put the statement(s) after `then` on a separate line, otherwise it will be considered a single `if` statement instead of a compound `if...else if...else...end if` statement.

Comment: In addition to the above, you have two `if…then` statements but only one `end if`.